# Python 3.6 Basemap Install

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I tried to install basemap for python 3.6 in the terminal but only getting the syntax error message:

```
>>> conda install basemap

  File "<stdin>", line 1
    conda install basemap
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone,  suggest a solution please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't write this in the python shell. Exit the python shell by typing *exit()* then type this command. This command is meant to be run in the main terminal not in python shell